# Neo4j Cypher query match for a node list on different labels

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This a part of my Neo4j Cypher query:

```
UNWIND ceNodeList AS ceNode 
WITH DISTINCT ceNode 
MATCH (childD:Decision:Profile )-[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode)
```

`ceNodeList` - is a list which may contain nodes with different labels. For example a mix of `Location` and `Employment`

Right now, the query matches `childD` in case `childD` `:REQUIRES` at least anyone node from `ceNodeList`. How to change this query in order to match only in case `childD` `:REQUIRES` at least one node for each different label? For example, one for `Location` and one for `Employment` (I'd like to be able to specify such set of labels because my entity has multiple labels at the same time).

**UPDATED**

This is my best try for now:)

```
UNWIND ceNodeList AS ceNode 
WITH DISTINCT ceNode 
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile )-[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode) 
WITH DISTINCT childD, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
WHERE size(ceNodes) > 1 
RETURN childD, ceNodes
```

How to instead of `size(ceNodes) > 1` check that `ceNodes` list contains at least one `Location` and one `Employment` node

**UPDATED1**

Finally I got this working with something like this:

```
UNWIND ceNodeList AS ceNode 
WITH DISTINCT ceNode 
MATCH (dg:DecisionGroup {id: -2})-[rdgd:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision:Profile )-[:REQUIRES]->(ceNode) 
WITH DISTINCT childD, collect(ceNode) as ceNodes 
WITH childD, ceNodes, reduce(ceNodeLabels = [], n IN ceNodes | ceNodeLabels + labels(n)) as ceNodeLabels  
WHERE all(x IN ['Location', 'Employment'] WHERE x IN ceNodeLabels) WITH childD
```

Not sure If I did ot in an optimal way..

Comment: please remove the UNWIND because you are looking at ceNodeList ONE at a TIME.  You can check if there exists at least one  label Location AND least one label Employment from the list ceNodeList.  Try it out and let me know the result.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I didn't get it (. Could you please shown an example?

Comment: If I try to `MATCH` with `ceNodeList` I get `Type mismatch: ceNodeList defined with conflicting type List<T> (expected Node)`

Comment: @jose_bacoy please see my updated question. This is best of what I have so far. How to change the validation from `size(ceNodes) > 1` to what I need?